# Connecting two devices from different network

Tags: networking, laptop, ip, connection, ibm-server

I have an IBM server running on static IPs.
Lets say it is **192.168.70.100** with mask **255.255.255.0**

And I have my laptop with IPv4 **10.0.X.X** with mask **255.255.0.0**
(I did with DHCP, I wanna do this way if it is possible).

How do I make them communicate together?

Can I connect my laptop to the server?

And if this is possible how would I do it ?

Comment: How are they connected physically? What networks, routers, switches, or other hardware do you have in between them? Is it just two devices on the same ethernet but with mismatching subnets?

Comment: I have ethernet wall socket where I can get network packets from, and I have internet hub for configuring connection between them. 
Lets go like this:
Wall Socket --> Hub with 8 ports (establishing internet)

Hub --> Laptop (establishing connection for laptop)

And I have the server with preset static IPs mentioned above.
Is it possible to somehow establish connection between them.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1462129/connect-to-a-device-having-static-ip-of-10-0-0-x-on-a-192-168-1-x-network?fbclid=IwAR3309_xUxOO1ZMTvt2Z4ryUawqr1KBu5XcBhn4Xt_P4r8K_oqMD8_0US28 The answer @LPChip provided solved the question for me!